# Booting archlinux USB installation on a MacBook

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, macos

I installed arch linux onto a USB and booted my main PC into arch successfully after selecting the drive when I was in the bios.

When I stck the USB in the macbook and booted into mac bootloader pressing the [option] button, the usb did not show up. But something like tails would and I can boot into that no problem.

Did I miss a step in order to get my USB to be compatiblw with a mac? It does have grub on it with the removable option added. Worked on PC flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC systems it will need to be set up as a UEFI boot image.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface  note pre 2008 vs newer macs have different UEFI needs https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Booting_64-bit_kernel_on_32-bit_UEFI

Comment: Umm, I do have an EFI partition with grub on it, but it won't show up on the mac boot menu. Any more ideas?

Comment: Asmodean, if it is pre 2008 you need a 32 bit efi grub image directions for arch are above just 64 bit grub or the default arch iso efi wont work on mac 2008 and before.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Archboot  this is stated to wor or look at

Comment: Lol, it turned out it was mac not willing to boot from an SD card, even if it is properly installed.